# redirect to "Shopping cart" page instead of "Checkout" page after registration

Tags: checkout, cart, register, coupon-codes

we provide coupon codes for only Registered customers.

so what we did is when a guest applied a coupon code it will display a message

"please register" , but when guest succesfully registered , its redirecting to "checkout" page instead of

"shopping Cart" page. i want to redirect to "shopping cart" page after registration.

please help me to find solution

thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried any code ?

Comment: not yet, i am working on that.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

1. Go to customer `accountcontroller` find _welcomeCustomer method.
2. Search for

> $successUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure' => true));

replace this code with your custom URL

> $successUrl = $this->_getUrl('customURL', array('_secure' => true));

*where is customURL input the page that you want the redirection to be made.

Comment: i went to this : /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/accountController.php

and searched above code and replaced "//index" by "checkout/cart/"

this is my site mycart link : http://sitename.com/index.php/checkout/cart/

but still its redirecting to checkout. what wrong i did?

Comment: this is my accountController.php code = 
http://pastebin.com/Q1j99Rzd please look at this

Comment: if you redirect the customer to my cart after registration it will show nothing because he did not add any items to his cart.

Comment: what happen is guest visit the site, than guest add some products to his cart, than he click on "my cart" button to

go to "my cart" page. than  he will apply coupon code. but guest can not apply coupon code.

than he will register and afte that it redirects to checkout page. than he can not able to apply coupon code , because

again customer need to go to "my cart" page. that is the problem, so i want to re direct to "mycart" page.

please see demo here  : http://demo1.kidsdial.com/

Comment: i understand now, but i can't think how to solve this problem now, because there is no "my cart" page. update your question in order to be more specific.

Comment: i edited the question.

Comment: here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499831/redirect-to-my-cart-page-instead-of-checkout-page-after-registration-in-mage/30501033#30501033  i got solution for "creating an acoount  = > Shopping cart" , what  i need to do for redirect   "Registered customers to " Shopping cart "page?

Comment: i don't if a redirection in my cart is possible, without having any items in the cart.

Comment: as we are giving coupon codes for only registered customers , we have to redirect registered customers to shoppping cart page

Comment: in your other comment you told me that you want when a guest is adding items to his cart and his going to apply the coupon code to be able too, but you have set only registered customers to be able to apply coupons, so i suggest let the guests apply coupon codes too. I am saying that because the cart page with items it's not a page , the items are adde to the cart dynamically and therefore i believe that cannot return to that cart page instance if you leave ,register and try to return.

Comment: but our client want only registered to apply coupons.

Comment: i mean use your logic, you leave the cart with the items added, you register  and then you wish to return to the cart with the items added but as a different user, as a registered customer. I don't if you can do this programmaticaly by holding somewhere your guest items and show that cart, i don't if you understood me.

Comment: i believe that your question can be marked as solved, with what you first asked.

Comment: ya, it solved , i will confirm in few minutes, please wait....

Comment: if you manage to pull that off please give me a feedback.

Comment: ya, sure..... thanks a lot for your support...  i will inform you soon,